# PHP script to retrieve data from mysql and write to mssql: syntax error when accented and special characters

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, charset

I’m running a php script that takes data from a mysql db and writes into a mssql db which I have no rights on except writing.
Tables in first DB, where I get data from, uses utf8_general_ci. Tables in the second DB, where I write to, uses Latin1_General_CI_AS.

I didn’t write this code but I’m asked to solve this problem.
The problem is that ANY accented character or symbol (like °, or even ‘) breaks the query and gives `“SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Incorrect syntax near…”`

The script uses PDO to fetch data and to write and its purpose is to write into a warehouse database to keep it updated basing on what happens in the database of the online shop (new users, new sells, user updates, etc.). The best would be to copy data as they are, keeping all the accented and special characters to keep data consistent especially for invoice info (names, addresses, etc.).

I’ve set up a custom log error

```
ini_set("error_log", DIR."/php-error.log");
```

Overwhelmed by desperation, I already tried to convert the strings before inserting them in the queries like this

```
  $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8'); 
  $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'ISO-8859-1'); 
  $string = utf8_decode($string);
  $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8'); // yes, a friend of mine told me to try that  because in some cases it inexplicably helped
```

I tried to set the charset after the connection

```
  $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
  $conn->exec("SET NAMES 'latin1'; SET CHARACTER SET latin1;");
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

I also tried to prefix the strings in the query with the N character -> No result.

I even tried something dirty like setting an array of unwanted accented characters and replacing them with `strtr()`. No result. I don’t know why but in this case the characters seems to stay as they are like the accented characters are not “detected” in the `strtr()` but they hell are in the query (?!?!?!?).

The even stranger thing is that it seems that if I run this code from browser I have no errors in the log and query works. If the script is ran through cronjob it does.
Can anyone help pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: To be clear, you want to destructively and irreversibly change the text when going from one database to another? I ask, because if I was given this assignment, that's the first thing I'd confirm with whomever gave it to me. At first glance, this seems like "here's the current situation" which may or may not be a requirement.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you for your reply. I realize I was not that clear. The script writes into a warehouse database to keep it updated basing on what happens in the database of the online shop (new users, new sells, user updates, etc.). 
So, to answer your question, the best would be to copy data as they are, keeping all the accented and special characters to keep data consistent especially for invoice info (names, addresses, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use any encode/decode functions.
- `SET NAMES 'latin1';` is telling MySQL that the *client* (PHP) code is encoded in latin1.
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see what encoding will be *stored* in the column (in MySQL).  I do not know how to specify MSSql's charset.
- When both parts are MySQL, those two `CHARACTER SETs` do not need to be the same; the encoding will be converted as needed during `INSERT`/`SELECT`.
- To help further, please provide hex of some string that is having trouble.  Try to do the hex in the database if relevant, else do it in PHP with `bin2hex()`.
- MySQL:  `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot for these suggestions.
Fortunately, I don’t have to try anything because server admins helped me to call the php page as a url resource and not as a php script. Everything seems working fine since then.

Comment: @MMJ - Geez; I've been using PHP for 20 years; I never heard of "php page as a url resource and not as a php script".